# Read data from Firestore Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to read data from Cloud Firestore, but while doing this I get this error message:

> For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

And I don't know what to do to get rid of it. Maybe there is an easy way to fix this I haven't thought of yet...
I have been using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) google firebase tutorial but with no success.

The error message comes on the `documents` in the `for (document in documents)` part of the code
The code I am using is this:
`

```
fun Varer() {

    var firestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var docRef = firestore.collection("varer").document("varer")
    var source = Source.DEFAULT

    docRef.get(source).addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            var v1 = VareFB(
                tittel = document["tittel"].toString(),
                pris = document.getDouble("pris"),
                beskrivelse = document["beskrivelse"].toString(),
                bildeID = document["bildeID"].toString(),
            )
            varerListe.add(v1)
            Log.d(TAG, document["tittel"].toString())
            Log.d(TAG, v1.toString())
        }
    }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Feil med henting av varer: ", exception)
            }
}
```

`

```
data class VareFB (
    val tittel: String,
    val pris: Double?,
    val beskrivelse: String,
    val bildeID: String,
) {
    @Exclude
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "tittel" to tittel,
            "pris" to pris,
            "beskrivelse" to beskrivelse,
            "bildeID" to bildeID,
        )
    }

}
```

`

```
object VarerObject {
    var varerListe = mutableListOf<VareFB>()
}
```

`

**Edit:**

```
fun Varer() {

    var firestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var docRef = firestore.collection("varer").document("varer")
    var source = Source.DEFAULT

    docRef.get(source).addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            var v1 = VareFB(
                tittel = document["tittel"].toString(),
                pris = document.getDouble("pris"),
                beskrivelse = document["beskrivelse"].toString(),
                bildeID = document["bildeID"].toString(),
            )
            varerListe.add(v1)
            Log.d(TAG, document["tittel"].toString())
            Log.d(TAG, v1.toString())
        }
    }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Feil med henting av varer: ", exception)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`documents` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) object so there is no way you can iterate over it. To be able to iterate through the documents, you have to get the documents out of the QuerySnapshot object like this:

```
firestore.collection("varer").get(source).addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
    for (document in documents.documents) {
        //
    }
}
```

But in my opinion, it's a little confusing. So I would rather name the object that comes from the lambda expression `snapshot`:

```
//                                                               
firestore.collection("varer").get(source).addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
    for (document in snapshot.documents) {
        //             
    }
}
```

Comment: By using the lambda expression you wanted me to use (the last one you added) I now get another error. `Unresolved reference: documents`. Do you know why?

Comment: Which line of code produces that error? Please note that you have to change your code according to the new change.

Comment: The same line with the code that now says `for (document in snapshot.documents) {`

Comment: Have you also changed `.addOnSuccessListener { snapshot->` ?

Comment: Yes I have, sorry that I didn't write that in the previous reply.

Comment: Please edit your question and show me the entire code.

Comment: I have now edited the question to contain the newest version of the code

Comment: You have also to change `docRef.get(source)` to `firestore.collection("varer").get(source)` as my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Hey Magnus. Can I help you with other information? Did my answer help?